# Error with mpi4py after awhile of spawning, How to Debug

Tags: python, mpi, spawn, mpi4py

This is similar to a few questions on the internet, but this code seems to be working for awhile instead of returning an error instantly, which suggests to me it is maybe not just a host-file error?

I am running a code that spawns multiple MPI processes which then each create a loop, within which they send some data with bcast and scatter, then gathers data from those processes.  This runs the algorithm and saves data.  It then disconnects from the spawned comm, and creates another set of spawns on the next loop.  This works for a few minutes, then after around 300 files, it will spit this out:

```
[T7810:10898] [[50329,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file ../../../../../orte/mca/plm/base/plm_base_launch_support.c at line 758
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun was unable to start the specified application as it encountered an error.
More information may be available above.
```

I am testing this on a local machine (single node), so the end deployment will have multiple nodes that each spawn their own mpi processes within that node.  I am trying to figure out if this is an issue with testing the multiple nodes on my local machine and will work fine on the HPC or is a more serious error.

How can I debug this? Is there a way to be printing out what MPI is trying to do during, or monitor MPI, such as a verbose mode?

Answer (score 0):

Since MPI4PY is so close to MPI (logically, if not in terms of lines-of-code), one way to debug this is to write the C version of your program and see if the problem persists.  When you report this bug to OpenMPI, they are going to want a small c test case anyway.